# How to close (unload) a form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form that has some buttons, and when user click on a button, the form should be closed (unloaded). I used the following methods, but all generate error:

```
docmd.close me

unload me
```

What is the best way to close or unload a form in VBA (from code inside the form)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`DoCmd.Close` expects *ObjectType* as its first argument, followed by *ObjectName* which is a variant string as the object name.

So in the click event of a command button which is intended to close the current form, I use this ...

```vb
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
```

Comment: I did a test and found that DoCmd.Close also close current form.

Comment: @mans: Be careful using `DoCmd.Close` without any arguments.  It will close whatever object is active.  At runtime this is not likely to be an issue; but at design time, if you are stepping through the code, `DoCmd.Close` will close the Application object.  That is, it will kick you out of Access itself!  I do believe it prompts you to save any unsaved objects, but it is annoying nonetheless.  For that reason, I always do as @HansUp does, and use `DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name`.