# Unable to close VBA form

Tags: vba, forms

Real simple.
I have excel vba code which launches a form.
I have a close button on the form.
What would be the code to close the form?

Me.close doesn't work.
Indellisense doesn't seem to be giving me the right choice....

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452849/how-to-close-unload-a-form

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close (unload) a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452849/how-to-close-unload-a-form)

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to close the whole program then you should use

```
mainformname.close()
```

If you want to keep the main form open but hide the new form simply type

```
me.hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

`Unload Me` is what I use. But you dont really need a close button. The user can just click the X in the top right corner.